# how to convert the attached code to ES6 using Queryselector and addeventListener functions // what the new converted code will be?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-selectors, addeventlistener

how to convert the attached code to ES6 using Queryselector and addeventListener functions //  what the new converted code will be ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function on(){
document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif';
}
function off(){
document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif';
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Turn the pulp on or off !</h2>
<button onclick="on()">Turn on the light</button>
<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100px">
<button onclick="off()">Turn off the light</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>  
  <h2>Turn the pulp on or off !</h2>
  <button class="btn" id="button_On">Turn on the light</button>
  <img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100px" />
  <button id="button_Off">Turn off the light</button>
  <script>
    let btn_On = document.querySelector('#button_On');
    btn_On.addEventListener('click', function () {
      document.querySelector('#myImage').src = 'pic_bulbon.gif';
    });
    let btn_Off = document.querySelector('#button_Off');
    btn_Off.addEventListener('click', function () {
      document.querySelector('#myImage').src = 'pic_bulboff.gif';
    });
  </script>
  </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add script at end of the body otherwise, query selector can not find elements because HTML file is yet to lode. There we need to put  ...  at end.

Comment: You don't have to worry about where to place the script if you are using `DOMContentLoaded` event ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
  <h2>Turn the pulp on or off !</h2>
  <button id="btnTurnOn">Turn on the light</button>
  <img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100px">
  <button id="btnTurnOff">Turn off the light</button>
</body>
```

```js
const btnTurnOn = document.querySelector('#btnTurnOn');
const btnTurnOff = document.querySelector('#btnTurnOff');

btnTurnOn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#myImage').src = 'pic_bulbon.gif';
});

btnTurnOff.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#myImage').src = 'pic_bulboff.gif';
});
```